# UIButton set Text on top of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

How can i add a Text in a button which already contains an image. I've tried out various methods but the text is not visible. How can i make the text visible on top of the image ?

Can anyone help me !

Comment: Instead of setImage property use [myButton setBackgroundImage:myImage]; then use setTitle. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better way.

`UILabel *next=[ [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,65)];` 
 
`next.text=@"SIGN IN";`

 `next.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;`

 `next.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0 ];`
`next.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];`
 `[self.button addSubview:next];`

Answer (score 3):

try setting the `backgroundImage` property of button

```
[self.buttonWithTextAndImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonWithTextAndImage setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background image of the button, instead of the image, using `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

Answer (score 1):

If your button's image set in **setImage** state, then the text is not going to display on Button.

If you have to display name on button then we have to set **setBackgroundImage** and then you can set the title for button.

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:YOURIMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:YOURTITLE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set background image and title on a button as-

```
[self.m_myBetButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.m_myBetButton setTitle:@"BUTTON TITLE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This must work.

Comment: Lol so many answer while I was writing the answer. :D This shows how vibrant is iOS community :)

Answer (score 0):

something, that worked fine for me: I set the Button in InterfaceBuilder and use the tiny Icons near "Position" to define the position of the text. Mouseover shows the code which is applied by InterfaceBuilder.
Now if the text doesn't show, due to color, i use a reference to the button and set an attributedTitle:

```
NSDictionary *atts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString *example = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"myText" attributes:atts];
    [myExampleButton setAttributedTitle:example];
```